# A simple number theory problem

Tags: number-theory

Prove the following question:

Suppose a and m be natural numbers such that gcd(a,m)$\neq $1. prove that $a^{\phi (m)}\neq 1$ (mod m)

Comment: You can use the Euler's theorem.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Let $d=\gcd(a,m)$.  Suppose that $a^{\varphi(m)}\equiv 1\pmod{m}$. Then $m$ divides $a^{\varphi(m)}-1$, so $d$ divides $a^{\varphi(m)}-1$. But $d$ divides $a^{\varphi(m)}$, so $d$ divides $1$. This is impossible, since $d\gt 1$.

**Remark:** Note that the only property  of $\varphi(m)$ that was used is the fact that $\varphi(m)\ne 0$.

Comment: Thank you very much! You solution is much clearer.

Comment: You are welcome.

Answer (score 2):

**Hint** $\ $ Contrapositively $\ d\mid a\mid \color{#c00}{a^\phi},\ \ d\mid m\mid \color{#0a0}{a^\phi\!-1} \,\Rightarrow\, d\mid 1 = \color{#c00}{a^\phi}-(\color{#0a0}{a^\phi\!-1}),\ $ so $\ (a,m)=1.$

**Remark** $\ $  More generally we could deduce it as a special case of

**Theorem** $\ \ a\mid A,\,\ b\mid B\ \Rightarrow\ (a,b)\mid (A,B)$

**Proof** $\quad\ \ \  \begin{eqnarray}(a,b)\mid a\mid A\\ (a,b)\mid b\mid B\end{eqnarray}\ \  $ so $\ \ (a,b)\mid A,B\,\Rightarrow\,(a,b)\mid (A,B)\quad $ **QED**

Therefore  $\ \ a\mid a^\phi,\,\ m\mid a^\phi\!-1\,\Rightarrow\,(a,m)\mid (a^\phi,a^\phi\!-1)=1$

Comment: Thank you also for providing some insights into the problem.

Comment: @LiangkaiHu The reason I organized the proof that way was to motivate the Theorem, which comes in very handy in number theory. It may be very slightly more effort this way, but I guarantee you it is time well-spent. If anything is unclear please feel welcome to ask questions.